# Anylogic: How to link a radio button to a variable with type double?

Tags: variables, radio-button, double, anylogic

I'd like to use radio buttons in my Anylogic model to make it easier to change values before a simulation. I am running different szenarios (szenario A: electricity price Winter (Strompreis Winter); szenario B: electricity price Summer (Strompreis Sommer), szenario C: electrity price Fall (Strompreis Übergang) and I don't want to change all the formulas in my model when using another electricity price. Instead, I would like to just use the variable "electricityprice" in my formulas and then change the value(s) of that variable by using the radio button.
I tried to use a radio button to set the value of the variable "electricityprice" (Strompreis) / link it to the variable "electricityprice" (Strompreis). This is because I have hourly electricity prices for several type weeks (e.g. electricityprice winter)  which are shown by dynamic variable who read them from an excel file.

[Anylogic screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVeKg.png)

[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM7hM.png)

In the field Action of the radio button I typed:

```
   if (value==0) {
    Strompreis = StrompreisWinter;
}
else if (value==1) {
    Strompreis = StrompreisSommer;
}
else if (value==2) {
    Strompreis = StrompreisÜbergang;
    }
```

However, the electricity prices are of type double (e.g. 4.45€). It's only possible to link the radio buttons to a variable of type int. Any idea how I could solve that problem? Thank you!

Comment: maybe to clarify my previous answers: your code here is 100% fine. But I am not sure you understand what it does: if the user choose radio button option 1 (value==0), then the variable "electricityprice" is set to whatever value "electricitypriceWinter" has. Both "electricitypriceWinter" *AND* "electricityprice" can be double, no problem.

Comment: that is exactly what I want. unfortunately, anylogic is complaining about errors. In the property of the radio button there is a field "link to". I can only link the radio button to the variable when I choose the type int in the variables property. If double is selected, I can't link it. The error is "wrong parameter type".

Comment: If I select int for the type of the variable, it does show the error "type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int" for the field "Action" in the radio button property. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like I can just ignore the error "wrong parameter type". The simulation is working. And the variable does take on the value of the dynamic variable. However, it does only take on the current value when I click on a button and then it stays like that. How can I update it regularly/every hour?

Comment: you should not use the "Link" feature in your case. It can only link to an int-variable which can be used to either store the user choice from the last click or change the radio button choice programmatically. It has *nothing* to do with your code, which is fine.

Comment: if you want to use the regular update, use my suggestions from below (function "getCurrentElecPrice" but amended for hours). Alternatively, take a screenshot from the data (no need for correct numbers, just the correct format) and I can create a dummy model for you, no prob.

Comment: that would be great. I updated some data in my original post but you could also imagine some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example model that does what you want, hope this helps :-)

[download](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dqu4ccge0vv072t/AABLfIKExvmcRGXR-TPY-0FSa?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Several things are "off" here:

When AnyLogic says you can only use Int values for radio buttons, they mean this: the value relates to the user choice made. Your radio button has 3 choices in your example so the value can only be 0, 1 or 2. Nothing else. How you map them to any action is your business.

Next: Your issue should be solved differently. Either, you want to dynamically change a variable value over the course of a year (case 1). Or you want the user to change a variable value during runtime (case 2).

### Case 1: dynamically change variable value

Several ways to do this: if you only have 4 seasons, probably easiest to use a simple mapping function "getCurrentElecPrice" that returns a different dbase value based on the current season:
[image]

### Case 2: let user change value

You can always change a variable directly at runtime: click on it and then on the value to edit it, see below:
[image]

More elegantly, you might want to use a slider or editbox. Or a radio button with limited options, but you wouldn't use that for a price, like in your case.

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Case 1: I only have the personal learning edition, so I can't work with databases right?
Case 2 doesn't work for me either. The model "runs for a week" and the electricity price changes every hour. Could you explain why I wouldn't use a radio button?

Comment: I meant that I can only link the radio button to variables of type int. I tried it with a variable of type double and it didn't work

Comment: re radio buttons: exactly. it can only be an int number because the radio options are separate options, it is either 0, 1 or 2. you cannot opt for 1.5!

Comment: re your case: can you re-explain what you would want the radio for? be specific, send screens, etc. and I can create an example model for you. (edit your original question with more details)

Comment: alright. just did that. hope it's more clear now. let me know if there are still question.